# Android Studio 3.5 Beta: App not installing even though build successful

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I installed Android Studio 3.5 beta version. When I try to run the app using the run button as I used to on 3.4 version, the build starts and is successful but the app doesn't get installed.

These are the logs

```
Executing tasks: [:Makano:assembleDebug] in project /home/varun/customerandroid


> Configure project :base
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.databinding.enableV2
Databinding v1 is removed.



> Configure project :Makano
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.databinding.enableV2
Databinding v1 is removed.


registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :menu
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.databinding.enableV2
Databinding v1 is removed.



> Configure project :ratemyapp
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.databinding.enableV2
Databinding v1 is removed.



> Task :base:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :base:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :base:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Makano:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Makano:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/varun/customerandroid/Makano/google-services.json

> Task :ratemyapp:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:parseDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:parseDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:parseDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :base:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :base:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :menu:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :menu:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :base:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :ratemyapp:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :ratemyapp:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Makano:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Makano:processDebugManifest
/home/varun/customerandroid/Makano/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:38:5-40:31 Warning:
    uses-permission#android.permission.SEND_SMS was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:38 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present
/home/varun/customerandroid/Makano/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:41:5-43:31 Warning:
    uses-permission#android.permission.BLUETOOTH was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:41 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :Makano:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Task :Makano:generateDebugSources
> Task :Makano:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Makano:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
/home/varun/customerandroid/Makano/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:4651: warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
/home/varun/customerandroid/Makano/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:4658: warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.

> Task :Makano:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Makano:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :Makano:mergeDebugResources
> Task :Makano:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:processDebugResources
> Task :Makano:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:kaptDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Makano:packageDebug
> Task :Makano:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
96 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 90 up-to-date
```

The device is being detected because it shows in Studio on the left side of the run button. This is a new feature because on earlier version I used to get a window where I could chose the device to run. Now I can select it from this menu and then click the run button and build starts. But the app never installs. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: go to **gradle.properties** file and put this line : `android.databinding.enableV2=true` Now, sync project and try again.

Comment: @JeelVankhede This is already there :(

Comment: Always use stable version!!

Comment: For dialog : Go to Run menu -> choose edit configuration -> select android application -> select app in general option -> In this option showing "Deployment Target Options" then Target choose "Open Select Deployment Target Dialog"

Comment: @SumitShukla Stable version won't run my code. This was necessary

Comment: @PratikPanawala This option is not there :(

Comment: After this operation, application apk should be in app->build->output->apk-> can you check apk is there or not?

Comment: @PratikPanawala Yeah apk is there, just not being installed on phone

Comment: @varunkr if apk is being generated then it's probably issue of adb not getting connected to device/emulator, try restarting adb. use commands `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: @JeelVankhede I tried that many times. Switched back to 3.4 for now since I don't need 3.5 anymore, at least not now.

Comment: Yes, that's why they provide ability to run all stable to canary versions alongside.